# Problem XML Encoding

Tags: java, xml

I use the iterator-style API to parse an XML stream with Stax.

I developed a small code that cuts a large XML file into several files.

Then I read correctly the flow but when writing, I get files with odd characters (encoding problem)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

        int offre=0;
        int i=0,j=0;
        String Data="";
        String nom="flux0.xml";
        XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new java.io.FileInputStream("CJ.xml"));
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(nom);
        XMLOutputFactory xmlof = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventWriter writer = xmlof.createXMLEventWriter(output);
        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        while (reader.hasNext() /*&& j<3000*/)
        {
            XMLEvent event = (XMLEvent) reader.next();

            if (event.isStartElement())
            {
                if (event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart() == "OFFER")
                {
                    offre++;
                }
            }
            if(offre==5000)
            {
                i++;
                nom="flux"+i+".xml";
                output = new FileOutputStream(nom);
                writer= xmlof.createXMLEventWriter(output);


                if (event.getEventType() == event.CHARACTERS)
                {

                    Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
                    String texte=characters.getData();
                    CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
                    Data= new String(encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(texte.toCharArray())).array());
                    writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(Data));
                }
                  else
                  {
                    writer.add(event);
                  }
                nom="flux"+i+".xml";
                offre=0;
            }
              else
              {
                if (event.getEventType() == event.CHARACTERS)
                {
                    Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
                    String texte=characters.getData();
                    CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
                    Data= new String(encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(texte.toCharArray())).array());
                    writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(Data));
                }
                  else
                  {
                    writer.add(event);
                  }
               }
               writer.flush();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code the char encoding is forced to your writer

```
    String outputEncoding = "UTF-8";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(aFile);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, outputEncoding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this code block totally unnecessary?

```
Characters characters = event.asCharacters();
String texte=characters.getData();
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
Data= new String(encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(texte.toCharArray())).array());
writer.add(eventFactory.createCharacters(Data));
```

Why can't you just pass the event through to the writer like for other events? If you need the file in a specififc encoding then there is a factory method taking a charset as parameter:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(nom);
XMLOutputFactory xmlof = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventWriter writer = xmlof.createXMLEventWriter(output, "utf-8");
```

Comment: I try this:
XMLEventWriter writer = xmlof.createXMLEventWriter(output, "utf-8");

and this is a small extracted result: